# How to set the control's initial position in dialog in MFC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

In MFC, I've made a resizing dialog in MFC and I put one control on a dialog like slider.
After the build, I found that the slider does not move when I resize the dialog.
So I made `OnSize()` then I set the position. It works.
However, there is one problem which is the different between control's first position and second position in `Onsize()`.

So I want to make so that there is no difference in control's position between the first run dialog and after resizing.

How to set the control's initial position in dialog in MFC?

Answer (score 3):

Ignore all `WM_SIZE` messages you receive until `OnInitDialog` is executed...

`WM_INITDIALOG` is fired when the dialog ist just before to be shown or was already shown (if it has the visible style).